# Selenium WebDriver “find_element_by_xpath” on WebElement

Tags: python, html, selenium

```html
<figcaption class="ncss-row">
   <div class="ncss-col-sm-12 full">
     <div class="figcaption-content">
       <div class="copy-container ta-sm-c bg-white pt6-sm pb7-sm pb5-lg">
         <h3 class="ncss-brand u-uppercase text-color-grey mb-1-sm mb0-md mb-3-lg fs12-sm fs14-md">
          Air Jordan XI<!-- -->&nbsp;
         </h3>
         <h6 class="ncss-brand u-uppercase fs20-sm fs24-md fs28-lg">Black/Red<!-- -->&nbsp;
         </h6>
       </div>
       <div data-qa="shop-now-cta" class="cta-container bg-white pt6-sm pb7-sm pb5-lg prl12-sm pb8-sm 
        pt8-lg ta-sm-c xh-highlight">
          <div>
            <button class="cta-btn u-uppercase ncss-btn text-color-white ncss-brand d-sm-b d-lg-ib pr5- 
             sm pl5-sm pt3-sm pb3-sm d-sm-ib bg-black test-buyable buyable-full-width buyable-feed" 
             data-qa="notify-me-cta theme-feed">通知我
            </button>
          </div>
       </div>
     </div>
    </div>
</figcaption>
```

I want to locate the button by find_element_xpath, bu it always always appears

```
[<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="10bf8a8d83d1b36188a6b1e41856c052", element="0.5294218443885808-2")>]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
    url = 'https://www.nike.com/cn/launch/'
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get(url)
elements = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//figure/div/div/figcaption/div/div/div[2]/div/button').text
print(elements)
```

Comment: `browser. find_elements_by_css_selector('figcaption div div div div button')[0]`
Try to use `find_elements_by_css_selector` it will work

Answer (score 1):

To Click on the Button Induce `WebDriverWait` and wait for `element_to_be_clickable`() And use following Css selector.

```
WebDriverWait(browser,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'div[data-qa="shop-now-cta"] button[data-qa="notify-me-cta theme-feed"]'))).click()
```

You need to import following libraries.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

**Edited**

To get the Text of the button use below code.use `get_attribute("textContent")` 
Or `get_attribute("innerHTML")` since the item text is hidden on the page.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium import webdriver

browser=webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get("https://www.nike.com/cn/launch/")
print(WebDriverWait(browser,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'div[data-qa="shop-now-cta"] button[data-qa="notify-me-cta theme-feed"]'))).get_attribute("textContent"))
```

Comment: very thanks, and how to get the text of the button？

Comment: I tried to use your code, but it raise a new erroer.                                               
raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

Comment: You need to get the text before click the button not after.

Comment: I tried to use your code, but it raise another error                                   AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'text'

Comment: Can you post your code what you have tried in your original post?

Comment: @KaiserCai : instead of `find_elements_by_xpath()` it should be `find_element_by_xpath()` because `find_elements_by_xpath()` return list Not the element. use `find_element_by_xpath()`

Comment: very thanks. I updated my code again, but always returned empty text.

Comment: @KaiserCai : Try my code what I have posted on edited section.

Comment: run your code what posted on edited section always appeals TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace). and my code always returned empty text. this is my code:                       
`url = 'https://www.nike.com/cn/launch/'                                                    
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get(url)
elements=browser.find_element_by_xpath('//figure/div/div/figcaption/div/div/div[2]/div/button').text
 print(elements)`

Comment: amazing.very！！！ very very thanks. Why can't I locate it. Is it because of pseudo elements?

Comment: Yes it is.Feel free to accept the answer if it resolved your problem by clicking on hollow under down vote button.Thanks.